# SQL not fetching empty columns

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

i have a table that looks like this

```
students
----------
ID  | Name  | Class  | Pass
01  | Lisa  | 01     | 1D345
02  | Mike  | 03     | 22341
03  | Kim   | 03     | 
04  | Lance | 04     | 193CC
```

So I wanted to select those where Pass is not  empty, and I've tried

SELECT * FROM students WHERE Pass IS NOT NULL;

which returned the same table where it should have fetched me this

```
students
----------
ID  | Name  | Class  | Pass
01  | Lisa  | 01     | 1D345
02  | Mike  | 03     | 22341
04  | Lance | 04     | 193CC
```

I've also tried

SELECT * FROM students WHERE Pass IS NOT '';

and

SELECT * FROM students WHERE Pass !='';

both returning #1064 error, so what is the statement I should be using the fetch the required table?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: As a rule `both returning error` isn't much help, unless you actually include the error message.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, `pass` has a value other than `NULL`.  This might work:

```
WHERE Pass <> ''
```

This is equivalent to your last option, which should work in most databases (most databases support both `<>` and `!=` for inequality).

Or you might need to deal with spaces.

In MySQL, you can use a regular expression to be sure there is at least one alphanumeric character:

```
where pass regexp '[a-zA-Z0-9]'
```